# Jenkins slave unable to figure out java version

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, master-slave

```
[03/21/16 16:09:39] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 172.18.73.53:22.
[03/21/16 16:09:40] [SSH] Authentication successful.
[03/21/16 16:09:40] [SSH] The remote users environment is:
[03/21/16 16:09:40] [SSH] Checking java version of java
Couldn't figure out the Java version of java

[03/21/16 16:09:41] [SSH] Checking java version of /usr/bin/java
Couldn't figure out the Java version of /usr/bin/java
[03/21/16 16:09:41] [SSH] Checking java version of      /usr/java/default/bin/java
Couldn't figure out the Java version of /usr/java/default/bin/java
```

I am getting the above error on launching the slave

Answer (score 5):

It is trying to execute "/usr/bin/java -version" at first, then "/usr/java/default/bin/java -version" but both commands seem to be failing. This might be caused by wrong tool location on slave. 
You should first figure out the java executable location on your slave:

```
which java
```

Then, under slave configuration on Jenkins, enable "Tool Locations" checkbox and add your correct Java path there and save.

Comment: I solved this by adding java path not to 'Tool Locations', but 'Advanced-JavaPath'

Answer (score 4):

Check to see which java is on Slave

```
# which java
```

Then copy the java path and add it under **Advanced configuration** of **Launch Agents via ssh** block.

*Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes and Clouds > Configure node > Advanced section under Launch Agents via ssh block > "update Java path in there"*

Answer (score 0):

As Doruk said

> It is trying to execute "/usr/bin/java -version" at first, then "/usr/java/default/bin/java -version" but both commands seem to be failing.

However I couldn't find Java under the "Tool locations" option, so the solution that worked for me is to create a link from the java which you do run to the location Jenkins wants.

```
JAVA_IN=$(which java)
ln -s $JAVA_IN /usr/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to install JDK17 just for Jenkins:

1. Download: https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?arch=any&os=linux&version=17
2. Copy tgz to your jenkins node (agent) root e.g. to `/var/jenkins`.
3. Unpack tgz.
4. Rename unpacked directory from "jdk-..." to "jdk".
5. Check version: `/var/jenkins/jdk/bin/java -version`

This steps should work for any Linux agent.